# Android.mk jar file import java.lang.Error: packaging failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, emma, android.mk

I have recently started android application development in AOSP and came across an agenda of getting code coverage for manual testing scenarios. I came across an option of using an **emma.jar** library to get the same done. But when I use the same the jar file as a part of my Android AOSP project, the library is added and compilation was successful. During run time when I try to access a function, the application crashes with the following error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.panasonic.dairse.logger.loggerapp, PID: 4843
>       java.lang.Error: packaging failure: class [com.vladium.logging.ILogLevels] 
>       not found {java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vladium.logging.ILogLevels}

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in Your "Manifest.xml"

```
 <application.....>
 //add this line
 <activity name = "com.vladium.logging.ILogLevels">
 </application>
```

Comment: The class is a part of the jar library. As a result the class changes in each execution of the application. A similar error is generated at a later time with the class name "com.vladium.utils.IntSet"

Comment: In that case you must check newer version of your jar library, or contact the provider

Comment: This library is a part of the android sdk and also a part of the AOSP source. I got the library from the AOSP source. Thank you for your suggestion i shall look for a newer version of the same library.

Comment: As suggested I have tried using the latest available online version emma-2.1.5320.jar as well as the available emma.jar from android AOSP. Both cases I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your proguard rules for emma.

```
-keep class com.vladium.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: I do not have any progaurd files as such, is it mandatory that I have to add one and mention to keep the class ?

Comment: As per your suggestion I have tried adding the progaurd.files but still the same error persists.